# How I can get window size and position in extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs4

How I can get window position(xy) and size in extjs 4.

Comment: You can use jQuery with EXT: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Using_Ext_With_jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
var height = Ext.getCmp('win1').getSize().height;
    var width = Ext.getCmp('win1').getSize().width;
});
```

Comment: `new Ext.Window({
            title:'1',
            id:'win_screen1',
            closable:false,
            width:200,
            height:200,
            x:10,
            y:30,
            resizable:true         
        }).show()` its my window now how i can get position and size

Comment: `Ext.getCmp('win_screen1').getSize().height;` its running. :-)

Comment: @Asif because "win_screen1" is your Window id .Dont forget to Vote Up and Mark as anwser :)

Comment: @Asif I voted to reject your edit as too radical; if you have different code that accomplishes your goal, you can post your own answer.

Comment: How to get the global window object and it's dimensions?